# Is there a way to run pandas run_sql_query asynchronously?

Tags: python, pandas, asynchronous, async-await

I am reading data from a Postgres DB with `n` queries. Each of these queries may take a considerable amount of time to execute on the DB so I would like to execute them asynchronously.

I am trying to accomplish this via `async` module but with no luck

```py
class Test:

    async def collect_items(self, conn_):
        await pd.read_sql_query(items_query_string, conn_)

    async def test_items(self, conn_):
        self.item_df = self.collect_items(conn_)

    async def collect_stockout(self, conn_):
        await pd.read_sql_query(stockout_query_string), conn_)

    async def test_stockout(self, conn_):
        self.so_df = self.collect_stockout(conn_)

    async def _collect_all_async(self, conn_):
        await asyncio.gather(self.test_items(conn_), self.test_stockout(conn_))

    def collect_all(self, conn_):
        asyncio.run(self._collect_all_async(conn_))
```

However when I call `collect_all` I would like to wait for all the queries to complete and this is not the case since it returns instantly without properly setting `self.item_df` and `self.so_df`

Why is that the case?